# Installing Ubuntu 19.04 OVER window 10

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, 19.04

at first.

I used to use Ubuntu 18.04 on my old laptop.

now I bought a new one [HP] and wanted to replace the current windows 10 on my new laptop with Ubuntu 19.04

the laptop use UEFI 'what ever' and save-boot 
I have read something about this on google It's prevent the boot for some linux distros if they install alongside windows.

so If I just install Ubuntu over the whole disk [and removed windows] will this make some problem to me because I don't really know how this work and what is the advantages or disadvantages of such thing

Should I disable the save-boot before installing Ubuntu or all this will never matter after the installation

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Your post contains more thoughts than a question ([ask]). What is your actual intent? Do you _want_ to keep, or replace Windows? And what have you tried so far? Modern Ubuntu can be installed on a UEFI system, both as a single system or dual-boot, see [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Just 1 thing; if you leave the recovery partition as it is you can always restore the system to the old state(ie. windows)

Comment: If just starting out with Ubuntu, better to dual boot or keep Windows for now. And do a full backup of Windows to another drive or larger flash drive, some install options will erase entire drive including recovery or backup partitions on drive. See:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi